# Different results in eloquent and pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 5.2 and pgsql in an application. The problem is I run a query via eloquent and it returns no result, however if I dump the query and parameters and run it manually at pgadmin I see the results.

The code:

```
$stamps= Stamp::where('batch', $batch)
                ->orderBy('code')
                ->get();

echo json_ecode($stamps); 
// OUT: []

echo Stamp::where('batch', $batch)
            ->orderBy('code')
            ->toSql() . ' - ' . $batch;
// OUT: select * from "stamp" where "batch" = ? and "stamp"."deleted_at" is null order by "code" asc - ea64ea442977a9a16afd0fb5f4690432
```

If I copy and paste the query dumped in the pgadmin I get my expected results.

The batch comes in the URL via a call from another system, an HTTP post. In doesnt come in the body of the request, it is in the URL itself. I cannot change the other system.

There is probably smething very dumb on it, but I cannot see. Does anyone can help here?

Comment: Posting here table schema would help a bit.

Comment: I just found out the problem. What happens is that I send a request to the other system with the batch code and it replies. What I wasnt expecting is that the answer came before the bacth code get saved in the stamp. Since it wasnt saved yet it doesnt exist by that time. When I tried manually it was already saved and then I got the right results. Sorry for the incovenience =/

I am still surprised that a request and reply can be quicker than save in the db locally in the server.